# How can I see the full command Ant uses in the Java task?

Tags: java, ant, command-line

I'm having some trouble with a <java> task not executing the way I expect it to and want to see the actual text of the command ant is calling on the command line so I can check to see if it is what I expect. Is there a way to do this?

Trying to Google for how to do this is very frustrating since all I get is a lot of information about how to set the command line arguments that get passed in ant. I am already doing that, but want to know that what's getting executed it what I expect before I start digging into other possible issues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ ant -verbose -debug ...
```

should display the command used (and much more).

Comment: I was hoping there was something more targeted, but this will do, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can run ant in debug mode using:
    ant -d
It should dump all the information you needed in this context.